# Display Optional Content for AdBlock Users on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, plaintext, adblock

I am trying to set up some sort of conditional, non-intrusive text box that shows up only for people using AdBlock. I am adamantly and emphatically opposed to popups or locking the content of my website to AdBlock users. I simply want to have a small section of plain text show up that says, *“Hey, you! Before you read on, we ask that you consider whitelisting us on AdBlock. (etc. etc. etc.)”*. I want people to be able to scroll past it without issue and not have their experience with my website be impacted if they choose not to whitelist me; I'm not out to coerce anyone or annoy anyone, I just want to make my case, in brief, that I don't run obstructive, malware-filled ads and it would be great if they supported me. And I don't want it to show up if someone doesn't have Adblock enabled.

I'm ***not*** very savvy with HTML, but if someone can clearly instruct me where exactly to put some code in to my website, I would be open to an option that involves editing my website's code. Otherwise, a plugin that I've overlooked would be really helpful. I've looked around but most of what I've found is something that puts a giant sticky on the page to obstruct peoples' view until they whitelist. Again, I don't want that. That is exactly the reason people got AdBlock to begin with. People who use such countermeasures are fundamentally missing the point. (/rant)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/ad-blocking-detector/
Read this article:- https://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-detect-and-stop-adblock-in-wordpress/

Hope its working for you. try this and let me know